# Webpack Split code on wordpress site according pages. How to do this

Tags: wordpress, webpack

I am very much overwhelmed with Webpack. I am just learning it but want some guidance on how I can split code for CSS and js on Wordpress site for every page dynamically. 
manually this is time-consuming to filter css and js  and include it inside WordPress

Comment: Here you have my whole example containing css and js for individual pages in wordpress and many more ;) [docker-wordpress-xdebug](https://github.com/tomik23/docker-wordpress-xdebug)

Comment: any VIDEO tutorial I can get. this is going beyond my heaD

Comment: But thanks for your help. This is useful definitely, but I m consuming a lot of time to understand and not sure it will be able to accomplish things